# Different Result of plt.imshow() and cv2.imshow() in Jupyter

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to change to image color to Gray on Jupyter Notebook
it's confusing that using the cv2.imshow("gray", gray_image) can show the grayscale image in the alert window.
[Result of cv2.imshow("gray", gray_image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fy4F.png)

And I use the plt.imshow(gray_image) can not show the grayscale image but it is green.
[Result of plt.imshow(gray_image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgF2S.png)

**So, how can I show the grayscale which is the result of cv2.imshow(gray_image) on Jupyter Notebook? Thank You**
Here are my code:

```
import cv2
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

filename = 'photo.jpg'
img = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (540, 540))
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
#using cv2
cv2.imshow("gray",gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
#using plt
plt.imshow(gray_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use CV, just use cmap and map it to the grayscale. imshow works pretty well here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fname = 'Capture.png'
image = Image.open(fname).convert("L")
arr = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank You. So, what is the other approach of using CV?

Comment: @MattTin I believe cv2.imshow() should work.

Comment: Oh... because using cv2.imshow() can not show the result in Jupyter Notebook :(